# MSVC/Linux code for count_sprintf

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, stdio

I need function count_sprintf() that should return
number of characters (not inc nul byte) needed for the formatted buffer, on Win32 and on Linux.

```
int count_sprintf(const char *format, va_list ap);
```

There are subtle diffs beteen Win32 vs Linux in return value of vsnprintf when formatted value is longer than buffer size. That's why I ask for help.

Can you give portable code (#ifdef WIN32) for this function.

The function to be used like this:

```
int bufsize = 1 + count_snprintf(format, ap);  
char *buf = (char*)malloc(bufsize);  
vsnprintf(buf, bufsize, format, ap); // on WIN32, _vsnprint, on Linux, vsnprintf.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VS runtime has the _vscprintf which counts characters needed.

```
int count_sprintf(const char *format, va_list ap) {
#ifdef WIN32
  return _vscprintf(format, ap);
#else
  char c;
  return vsnprintf(&c, 1, format, ap);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you want a C solution, C++, or both.

In C++ there's an extremely easy way to solve this problem: Use streams instead of the `printf` line of functions.

In C I would suggest strongly taking care about any cases where you use a variable format string: They're liable to cause problems if the varargs to the function are even off by a little bit and there's no way for the compiler to help you. If the format is generated externally it's worse as you're basically open to any number of buffer overflow exploits. At least if you have a fixed format string you know how long it will be to start with, and some compilers can do format string checking on the varargs.

Comment: Hmm I am not aware of streams being capable of formatting according to printf-like format string to write the required function using streams ?

Comment: @Andrei The point is that with stream you don't need a format string at all.

Comment: The question is about printf-style formatting, %d etc. The punishment for calling printf and friends from C++, if it exists, is symbolic: the programmer is looked at as retard who cannot calculate Fibonaci number at compile-time using templates (even if he can), but apart from this, C++ compiler accepts it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use `asprintf`:

> ```
>    The  functions asprintf() and vasprintf() are analogs of sprintf(3) and
>    vsprintf(3), except that they allocate a string large  enough  to  hold
>    the output including the terminating null byte, and return a pointer to
>    it via the first argument.  This pointer should be passed to free(3) to
>    release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.
> ```

Comment: Hey, are you talking "Linux" or are you referring to a particular libc implementation, maybe? ;)

Comment: This is a GNU extension. glibc implements it. http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/asprintf.3.html

Comment: I was just trying to point out that your answer was only valid under the premise that Andrei uses glibc. There are plenty of incompatible alternatives out there that can be used for a multitude of reasons, not the least of which can be linking to glibc statically from within a proprietary program.

Comment: Yep, I knew what you were implying. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vsnprintf for this -- if you give it a size 0 buffer, it won't actually try to put anything in the buffer, but will still return the number of characters it would have output